# 'IF' statements in PHP

Tags: php, conditional-operator

i'M NOT SURE IF MY IF STATEMENTS ARE CORRECT -

- i want the code to end  **if** the variable `$answer` is not `'4'` or `'four'`.
- **If** the varible `$answer` is equal to 4 or four - program goes on to process the code.

any help gratefully received.

thanks

```
if( ! in_array($answer, array(4, 'four')))
{   
       //if answer is not in an array containing either 4 or four then..
        echo "You have entered the security question incorrectly. Your request will NOT be processed";
        exit();
}
else
{
    if ($from != "")
    {
            //test send mail to Melanie 
            mail($to, $subject, $contents, $from_header);

            // redirect back to url visitor came from
            $display_blockmsg = "Thank you, <b>$_POST[title] $_POST[firstname] $_POST[lastname]</b>, <br>
                                Your contact form details have been sent to us <br>
                                Your contact details are:<br><br>
                                <b>Address:</b> $_POST[address1] 
                                $_POST[address2],<br>
                                <b>City:</b> $_POST[city]<br>
                                <b>County:</b> $_POST[county]<br>
                                <b>Postcode:</b> $_POST[postcode]<br>
                                <b>Country:</b> $_POST[country]<br>
                                <b>Telephone:</b> $_POST[telephone]<br>
                                <b>email:</b> $_POST[from]<br><br>";        
  }
  else      
  {     
      $display_blockmsg = "<center><b>The email field</b> is empty. Please go back and complete this field.</center>"; 
  }
} //end of first else ...if
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

`if( ! in_array($answer, array('4', 'four')))` instead of `if( ! in_array($answer, array(4, 'four')))`

The $answer is a string and in array it is a numeric (integer)

So its better to use

`if( $answer != 4  && $answer != 'four')`

Answer (score 0):

An if control looks like

```
if(// condition is true) { 
  $that
} elseif (// another condition is true ) { 
  // anotherthing 
} else { 
  // somethingelse 
}
```

If you exit from an if statement, the rest of the code will not be executed.

The manual is very helpful - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php.

Answer (score 0):

For two options you don't need to create an array and use array option. Just use this:

```
if ($answer != 4 && $answer != 'four')
```

Comment: hi thanks so far my brackets are up the spout ?unfort. i can't repaste code ?  pls help